# How can I combine two separate JavaScript Axios result sets?

Tags: javascript, axios

I'm not well versed in Javascript but have a working program that uses Axios to query a range of values.  The program was written to look at a date range of information but the website only returns one month's worth of data at a time vs. a full set of several months.  I can do a query for each month but I'm not sure how to combine the axis results to have a full data set for the time range I want.

In the example below I'd like to combine data1 and data2.  Concat doesn't work so I'm looking to know how I can combine these two Axios results. (

```
const axios = require('axios');


async function getdata(urlString) {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(urlString);
      //const response = await axios.get(urlString);
} catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
}

     const urlString1 = 'https://www.recreation.gov/api/permits/233393/availability/month?  start_date=2023-07-01T00:00:00.000Z&commercial_acct=false&is_lottery=false';
     const urlString2 = 'https://www.recreation.gov/api/permits/233393/availability/month?start_date=2023-07-01T00:00:00.000Z&commercial_acct=false&is_lottery=false';
    const data1 = getdata(urlString1);


    const data2 = getdata(urlString2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you need:

```
const data1 = await getdata(urlString1);
const data2 = await getdata(urlString2);
let finalResult={...data1,...data2};
```

Comment: My finalResult payload only ends up with the payload values of data2.  Not sure why.

Comment: My finalResult line looks like the following since it needs to be restructured.  But it finalResult does not contain data1 and data2 it only contains the last entry in the let assignment.  If data1 is the last element, the finalResult contains data1.  If data2, it's only data2.

Comment: let {finalResult} = {...data1,...data2};